# msdeploy restore one site from package containing multiple sites

Tags: iis, restore, webdeploy

We create a msdeploy package for multiple sites as follows:

```
"c:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:manifest=MultipleSitesMultipleProviders.xml -dest:package=Test.zip,encryptPassword="password" -disableLink:ContentExtension -enableLink:AppPoolExtension
```

MultipleSitesMultipleProviders.xml

```
<sitemanifest>

   <appHostConfig path="SITE1" />
   <appPoolNetFx path="SITE1" />
   <dirPath path="C:\SITES\SITE1" />

   <appHostConfig path="SITE2" />
   <appPoolNetFx path="SITE2" />
   <dirPath path="C:\SITES\SITE2" />

   <appHostConfig path="SITE3" />
   <appPoolNetFx path="SITE3" />
   <dirPath path="C:\SITES\SITE3" />

</sitemanifest>
```

And here is how that package is then restored

```
"c:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -dest:auto -source:package=Test.zip,encryptPassword="password"
```

This restores all three sites.  The problem I'm trying to solve is how to tell msdeploy.exe to restore just one of the sites that I specify somehow.  I'm thinking this might be done using the [-skip rule](https://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/how-to-write-skip-and-replace-rules-for-msdeploy) which would tell the deploy to skip the two sites we don't want to install.  But I could not understand what the format of that this command might look like.

Is this even possible to do?  Any help would sure be appreciated!  Thank you.

Update: I think I found a way to do this through the UI.[image: Import Server or Site Package]
This installed just SITE1 and not SITE2 from a package that contained two sites.  I'd like to understand how to do this from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to do this.  All sites except SITE1 are excluded.  You need to work with archive.xml in the package zip file and come up with xpath expressions that will exclude the six elements that are generated by the six MultipleSitesMultipleProviders.xml entries.

The xpath that prevented the copying of the files was tricky because the element in archive.xml is '<MSDeploy.dirPath>' and you'd think the xpath expression would be //MSDeploy.dirPath[@path='C:\SITES\SITE3'] but that had didn't work but //dirPath[@path='C:\SITES\SITE3'] did work.  Don't know why that is the case.

```
-skip=xPath=//appHostConfig[@path='SITE2'] -skip:xPath=//appPoolNetFx[@Site='SITE2'] -skip:xPath=//dirPath[@path='C:\SITES\SITE2'] -skip=xPath=//appHostConfig[@path='SITE3'] -skip:xPath=//appPoolNetFx[@Site='SITE3'] -skip:xPath=//dirPath[@path='C:\SITES\SITE3']
```

I'm guessing there are other ways to do accomplish the same thing but I'm happy to just find something that worked!

Comment: Found that adding too many -skips caused a horrible degradation in performance of msdeploy and came up with a solution to reduce the number of -skips by using 'not' xpaths.   skip=xPath=//appHostConfig[not(@path='SITE1')] -skip:xPath=//appPoolNetFx[not(@Site='SITE1')] -skip:xPath=//dirPath[not(@path='C:\SITES\SITE1')].  (kind of weird talking to myself like this)